# What is the difference of use cases between scipy.interpolate.splrep and scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

- [scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, y, w=None, xb=None, xe=None, k=3, task=0, s=None, t=None, full_output=0, per=0, quiet=1)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html): Find the B-spline representation of 1-D curve. Given the set of data points `(x[i], y[i])` determine a smooth spline approximation of degree k on the interval `xb <= x <= xe`.
- [class scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y, w=None, bbox=[None, None], k=3, s=None, ext=0, check_finite=False)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline): One-dimensional smoothing spline fit to a given set of data points. Fits a spline y = spl(x) of degree k to the provided x, y data. s specifies the number of knots by specifying a smoothing condition.

It looks like quite the same, except this note in the `UnivariateSpline` manual:

> splrep: An older, non object-oriented wrapping of FITPACK

Return values are not described for `UnivariateSpline`.

So, is `UnivariateSpline` a replacement for `splrep`, or are use cases not totally the same?

Comment: looks like `splrep` gives you better control over the smoothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comment in the docs is outdated. Both interfaces wrap the same FITPACK implementation. So the difference us only that one interface is object-oriented, and the other one uses functions. (and is therefore easier to use in conjunction with the BSpline object)