# What is the difference between the various spline interpolators from Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

My goal is to calculate a smooth trajectory passing through a set of points as shown below. I have had a look at the available methods of [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html), and also the [scipy user guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html). However, the choice of the right method is not quite clear to me.

What is the difference between
[`BSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html),
[`splprep`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html),
[`splrep`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html),
[`UnivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html),
[`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d),
[`make_interp_spline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html) and
[`CubicSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html)?

According to the documentation, all functions compute some polynomial spline function through a sequence of input points. Which function should I select? A) What is the difference between a cubic spline and a B-spline of order 3? B) What is the difference between `splprep()` and `splrep()`? C) Why is `interp1d()` going to be deprecated?

I know I'm asking different questions here, but I don't see the point in splitting the questions up as I assume the answers will be related.

All in all, I find that the scipy.interpolate module is organized a little confusingly. I thought maybe I'm not the only one who has this impression, which is why I'm reaching out to SO.

---

Here's how far I've come. Below is some code that runs the different spline functions for some test data. It creates the figure below.

1. I've read somewhere: "All cubic splines can be represented as B-splines of order 3", and that "it's a matter of perspective which representation is more convenient". But why do I end up in different results if I use `CublicSpline` and any of the B-spline methods?
2. I found that it is possible to construct a `BSpline` object from the output of `splprep` and `splrep`, such that the results of `splev()` and `BSpline()` are equivalent. That way, we can convert the output of `splrep` and `splprep` into the object-oriented interface of `scipy.interpolate()`.
3. `splrep`, `UnivariateSpline` and `make_interp_spline` lead to the same result. In my 2D data, I need to apply the interpolation independently per data dimension that it works. The convenience function `interp1d` yields the same result, too. Related SO-question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61675281/)
4. `splprep` and `splrep` seem unrelated. Even if I compute `splprep` twice for every data axis independently (see p0_new), the result looks differently. I see in the docs that splprep computes the B-spline representation of an n-D curve. But should `splrep` and `splprep` not be related?
5. `splprep`, `splrep` and `UnivariateSpline` have a smoothing parameter, while other interpolators have no such parameter.
6. `splrep` pairs with `UnivariateSpline`. However, I couldn't find a matching object-oriented counterpart for `splprep`. Is there one?

[image: Comparison of different spline methods]

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = [[0, 0], [4, 4], [-1, 9], [-4, -1], [-1, -9], [4, -4], [0, 0]]
points = np.asarray(points)

n = 50 
ts = np.linspace(0, 1, len(points))
ts_new = np.linspace(0, 1, n)

(t0_0,c0_0,k0_0), u = splprep(points[:,[0]].T, s=0, k=3)
(t0_1,c0_1,k0_1), u = splprep(points[:,[1]].T, s=0, k=3)
p0_new = np.r_[np.asarray(splev(ts_new, (t0_0,c0_0,k0_0))),
               np.asarray(splev(ts_new, (t0_1,c0_1,k0_1))),
                ].T

# splprep/splev
(t1,c1,k1), u = splprep(points.T, s=0, k=3)
p1_new = splev(ts_new, (t1,c1,k1))
# BSpline from splprep
p2_new = BSpline(t1, np.asarray(c1).T, k=k1)(ts_new)
# splrep/splev (per dimension)
(t3_0,c3_0,k3_0) = splrep(ts, points[:,0].T, s=0, k=3)
(t3_1,c3_1,k3_1) = splrep(ts, points[:,1].T, s=0, k=3)
p3_new = np.c_[splev(ts_new, (t3_0,c3_0,k3_0)),
               splev(ts_new, (t3_1,c3_1,k3_1)),
               ]
# Bspline from splrep
p4_new = np.c_[BSpline(t3_0, np.asarray(c3_0), k=k3_0)(ts_new),
               BSpline(t3_1, np.asarray(c3_1), k=k3_1)(ts_new),
               ]
# UnivariateSpline
p5_new = np.c_[UnivariateSpline(ts, points[:,0], s=0, k=3)(ts_new),
               UnivariateSpline(ts, points[:,1], s=0, k=3)(ts_new),]
# make_interp_spline
p6_new = make_interp_spline(ts, points, k=3)(ts_new)
# CubicSpline
p7_new = CubicSpline(ts, points, bc_type="clamped")(ts_new)
# interp1d
p8_new = interp1d(ts, points.T, kind="cubic")(ts_new).T

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*points.T, "o-", label="Original points")
ax.plot(*p1_new,   "o-", label="1: splprep/splev")
ax.plot(*p2_new.T, "x-", label="1: BSpline from splprep")
ax.plot(*p3_new.T, "o-", label="2: splrep/splev")
ax.plot(*p4_new.T, "x-", label="2: BSpline from splrep")
ax.plot(*p5_new.T, "*-", label="2: UnivariateSpline")
ax.plot(*p6_new.T, "+-", label="2: make_interp_spline")
ax.plot(*p7_new.T, "x-", label="3: CubicSpline")
#ax.plot(*p8_new.T, "k+-", label="3: interp1d")
#ax.plot(*p0_new.T, "k+-", label="3: CubicSpline")
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.grid("on")
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between BSpline, splprep, splrep, UnivariateSpline, interp1d, make_interp_spline and CubicSpline?

- a `BSpline` object represents a spline function in terms of knots `t`, coefficients `c` and degree `k`. It does not know anything about the data `x, y`. It is a low-level implementation object, on par with `PPoly` --- think of PPoly vs BSpline as a change of basis.
- `make_interp_spline` constructs a spline (`BSpline`) which passes through the data `x` and `y` -- it's an *interpolating* spline, so that `spl(x) == y`. It can handle batches of data: if y is two-dimensional and the second dimension has length `n`, `make_interp_spline(x, y)` represents a stack of functions `y_1(x), y_2(x), ..., y_n(x)`.
- `CubicSpline` is similar but more limited: it only allows cubic splines, `k=3`. If you ever need to switch from cubics to e.g. linear interpolation, with `make_interp_spline` you just change `k=3` to `k=1` at the call site. OTOH, `CubicSpline` has some features BSpline does not: e.g. root-finding. It is a PPoly instance, not BSpline.
- interp1d is not deprecated, it is *legacy*. A useful part of interp1d is nearest/previous/next modes. The rest just delegates to make_interp_spline, so better use that directly.
- `splrep` constructs a *smoothing* spline function given data. The amount of smoothing is controlled by the `s` parameter, with `s=0` being interpolation. It returns not a BSpline but a tck tuple (knots, coefficients and degree).
- `splprep` constructs a smoothing spline curve in a parametric form. That is `(x(u), y(u))` not `y(x)`. Also returns tck-tuples.
- `UnivariateSpline` is equivalent to `splrep`.

Note that `scipy.interpolate` has grown organically. With at least four generations of developers over almost quarter century. And the FITPACK library which `splrep`, `splprep` and `UnivariateSpline` delegate to is from 1980s. `CubicSpline`, `BSpline` and `make_interp_spline` are not using FITPACK.

So in new code I personally would recommend `make_interp_spline` + `BSpline`; if you only need cubics, `CubicSpline` works, too.

> But why do I end up in different results if I use CublicSpline and any of the B-spline methods?

Boundary conditions. Both `make_interp_spline` and `CubicSpline` default to `not-a-knot`, and you can change it.
`splrep` et al only use `not-a-knot`.

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot for these clarifications. For computing a smooth trajectory in n-d, I think I should be using a parametric form then. Two immediate follow-up questions: 
**Q1)** Is there a "higher level" interface in scipy.interpolate for parametrized interpolators akin `make_interp_spline()`, or do I have to resort to `splprep()`? 
**Q2)** Is the math different between `splprep()` and `splrep`? I mean, couldn't I combine *n* independent `splrep()` evaluations to yield *x1(u), x2(u), ...* with *u∈[0,1]*. Or does `splprep()` solve a different problem?

Comment: Q1: not ATM. Easy to DIY though: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/1D.html#parametric-spline-curves

Comment: Q2: very similar. The parametric case simply has an extra summation over the components. See the Notes sections in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/19970/files#diff-4eab1cd2e7fd67bc31fe508749581b3bddd1c9deb6f827591e6163868d96af15 --- I believe these are faithful restatements of the FITPACK code and Dietckx 1982 paper (also referenced in the doctrings of the scipy PR).

Comment: Speaking of the scipy PR, user reviews are welcome.